# How to get URL client is coming from behind a reverse proxy?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

I have a `Controller` Action in which I:

1. Forward a URL to a 3rd party that the 3rd party re-directs the client to if an operation is successful.
2. The client then connects to the 3rd party and performs an operation.
3. If successful the 3rd party re-directs (using a 302) the client to the URL we told them at step 1.

This all works. Problem is the URL the Controller on the server tells the 3rd party about us built using:

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
var responseUrl = urlHelper.Action("Action", "Controller", new { id }, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

responseURL now looks like:

**"https://some.internal.domain/App/Action/1234"**.

The client however accessed the site using an address like:

**"https://example.com/App/Action/1234"**.

and they cannot access https://some.internal.domain externally.

So how can I build the absolute URL for the 3rd party to re-direct the client to *using the URL the client is accessing the site from*?

**UPDATE:** The above method should have worked it turns out the problem is am behind a Reverse Proxy (have re-worded the title to reflect this).

Comment: Doesn't `UrlHelper.Action` already work off of the request's host, if not doing it relatively? I don't think you have to tell it `Request.Url.Scheme` either. In any event, is there a reason `Request.Url` doesn't do what you're looking for?

Comment: I was hoping UrlHelper worked off the request but it does not appear to be happening.. I tell it scheme to get an absolute URL which is what I want. Perhaps I could use Request.Url and do my own string concatenation to construct the URL, trying now...

Comment: What *does* it return as the host, then? If not the current one? I'd look into [`UriBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) next, then. Or I think there might event be an overload even for the `Uri` constructor that will take a scheme (`Request.Url`), host (`Request.Url`), and path (`UrlHelper.Action(string, string, object)`). That'd at least be better than concatenation.

Comment: Unfortunately that too is giving https://some.internal.domain/App/Action/1234

Comment: Do you have a reverse proxy set up?

Comment: Yes! Apparently a TMG Reverse Proxy.. What now? :/

Comment: Hmm. That's gonna add some confusion. It seems like your best option is going to be checking the headers. I've never worked with that particular one, but most proxies add a header to upstream servers  to tell a bit about the incoming request. That makes it easy if outside requests are the only ones that go through the proxy.

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar problem. You basically have two options.

1. Use the URL Rewrite Module to rewrite your entire response by replacing/rewriting all pattern matched with `https://some.internal.domain` to `https://example.com/App`. You'll probably want to add certain conditions like only rewrite if the response type is of type `html/text` and what not.
2. Use an extension method. This method requires the Reverse Proxy in question to forward additional headers identifying where the original request came from (e.g. Azure Application Gateway sends a header named `X-Original-Host` but I think most other reverse proxies use `X-Forwarded-For` or some variant like `Winfrasoft X-Forwarded-For`). So based on the example provided you could do something like.

The helper could look like this

```
public static class UrlHelpers
{
    public static string GetUrlHostname(this UrlHelper url)
    {
        var hostname = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Original-Host"] ?? url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host;
        return hostname;
    }
}
```

And then to use it based on your example.

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext); 
var responseUrl = urlHelper.Action("Action", "Controller", new { id }, Request.Url.Scheme, urlHelper.GetUrlHostname());
```